# Difference between these 2 pieces of code for pre-flight in NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, express

First of all, I am a beginner with NodeJS, I am just watching some tutorials to get my feet wet: this question will probably sound very silly to anyone who has any Node experience.

In short, I am trying to allow pre-flight requests on my server, and the docs suggest I do this before my routes:

```
app.use(cors());

app.options('*', cors());
```

The tutorial I am following, on the other hand, proposes this:

```
app.use(cors())

app.options("*", (req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
})
```

So, what is the difference between these 2 pieces of code?
My current hypothesis is that

```
app.options('*', cors());
```

and

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

are equivalent, but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one allows you to set custom values for the allowed origin/methods/headers, but the CORS middleware actually supports this anyway - see the "Configuration Options" section on [this page](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html).

To explain a bit what's going on here:

- `app.use(cors())` means "use the `cors()` middleware for all methods and all paths".
- `app.options('*', cors())` means "use the `cors()` middleware for the `OPTIONS` method, for all paths (`*`)".
- `app.options('*', (req, res, next) => { /* ... */ })` means "use the provided function as a middleware for all `OPTIONS` requests, for all paths (`*`)".

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** yes, is the same

This `cors()` is from [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

> CORS is a node.js package for providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS with various options.

Basically is just a beautiful way to enable cors in routes with middleware.

You can check in [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js#L44) to see how it works, and check [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) other usage ways